# Password of user pi keeps changing

Tags: raspbian, ssh, login, password

I have a Raspberry Pi which is only used to display a web page on a screen. The pi connects to the internet over Wifi. When I'm on the same wifi I used to connect to my pi through SSH or VNC viewer using the default user "pi" and "raspberry" as password.

A few days ago I couldn't connect. When trying SSH I got: "Authentication failed, permission denied". Similar error with VNC.

I reset the password ("sudo passwd pi"). Problem solved, SSH access restored... VNC viewer worked as wel. But after 5 to 10 minutes, the password no longer worked. Resetting pw again still works, but only temporarily.

So it seems my password keeps changing? What can be the cause?

Comment: Using default user "pi" and "raspberry" is NOT recommended!

Comment: Yes I know. This is a test setup at home. Are you suggesting someone got access? I'm no longer using the default password.

Comment: I would have reinstalling the system, change password at first opportunity. Either your home network is hacked or someone at home is playing you a prank.

Comment: check your access.log and auth.log

Comment: The logs are clean. But I'm 1 step closer. The password only resets after a reboot.

Comment: I solved it by creating a new user and deleting the "pi" user afterwards. No problems so far.

Comment: @user63457 If you can figure out what went wrong and might be able to help others with a similar problem, you might like to post an answer with the solution.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Sorry I can't. My knowledge is too limited to find the root cause. And since I completely deleted the 'pi' user, I'm unable to replicate the problem to do a proper investigation.